# CSS: Apply property to element

Tags: css

I want to set box sizing border box to section element and I want ask its will be aplied to inside element looks like test class and etc class too? Or only to section element?

```
<section>
<ul class="test"></ul>
<li class="etc"></li>
</section>
```

Comment: could you rephrase your question please, it is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the HTML is wrong. Correct one:

```
<section>
  <ul class="test">
    <li class="etc"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

And to your question, it will be for `test` class only!

Comment: if i set section element only then will be applt yo ul and class elements too or not?

Comment: Will not be applied to ul but be applied to class.. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a style to "section" it wont be applied to "section ul" or "section li" if that was your question.

You can style all of those seperately.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/d4mu3/ No but as you can see things like font and color do. Also corrected the code in the fiddle.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbrdr.htm
If you look under the section labeled inheritance, you'll see that border's style properties are not inherited.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspcolor.htm
While color is on the other hand.

Use this to help you understand how your styles will affect other objects.

```
<section>
  <ul class="test">
    <li class="etc">test</li>
  </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: if i set section element only then will be applt yo ul and class elements too or not?

Comment: It entirely depends on the style you're using. I updated the answer with some helpful links on why border doesn't affect the children, but color does. It all has to do with inheritance, some properties affect the children. In the cases where you might apply one that affects the children, you could override it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not an element acquires properties of its ancestors depend on whether the properties are *inherited*.

[MDN `box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) says that `box-sizing` is *not* inherited.  This means that if `section` has `box-sizing`, that doesn't necessarily mean `<ul>` and `<li>` will have it.  You would have to select them separately.